# Encoding H264 video using Java

Tags: video, encoding, h.264

I am a newbie to video processing and hence forgive my ... if my questions are dumb.I want to encode an H.264 video pro grammatically(using Java) while having a close control on slices of the video. Please direct me towards any good wrapper and also programming tips/code snippets?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at it .. http://sourceforge.net/projects/h264avcjavaenco/files/

Though I did not use this...I use ffmpeg (written in c/c++) for this...Also you can use try this http://jffmpeg.sourceforge.net/ ... A port of ffmpeg in java